# Goland custom shell doesn't apply in debug mode

Tags: intellij-idea, cygwin, jetbrains-ide, goland

My Go program uses `librdkafka` which is a native C library.

Since I work on Windows, I use Cygwin + pkg-config to link with that library.
Since building the program is only possible in Cygwin, I had to link `Goland` with the Cygwin shell (instead of the default CMD)

[image]

It works fine when I run it (<kbd>Shift + F10</kbd>), but fails when I debug (<kbd>Shift + F9</kbd>)

[image]

This is the same error I get when I don't run it in Cygwin but in the default CMD. It's as if the custom shell/terminal configuration doesn't apply in Debug mode.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Terminal option in GoLand applies to the builtin terminal, not to the Run Configurations and their execution. As such, changing that option from default to something like PowerShell, cygwin's terminal, or WSL's bash does not have any effect on the compilation of your app.

Please add your cygwin's `bin` dir to the Windows PATH and then stop the IDE, logoff and then login and start the IDE again. The problem should be resolved.

Comment: Thanks, I added Cygwin's bin to PATH and now it gets past the `pkg-config` stage. However, it now says `inconsistent definitions for C.size_t` (probably something with x86/x64), I found that it happens when you run `go build` with `-gcflags "all=-N -l"` which is something that the debugger adds automatically. Is there a way to tinker with the debugging options and/or remove the `gcflags` part from the build?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. Those flags are required for debugging. The only reference that I found to be similar to your new problem is: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17723#issuecomment-257696920 If you have a small sample on how to reproduce this, I would be happy to assist you. Or feel free to ping me on Gophers Slack with the same handle as here.